# How can I get mooMasonry to work in this case?

Tags: select, mootools

I'm a MooTools newbie and I'm working in Contao which makes it even more confusing, but this is what I'm trying to do:

I have a list with 4 elements each of which contains a list (ul.level_2) of more lists. What I want to do is mason ul.level_2 so that all of its sublists are forced into a tight layout.

```
window.addEvent('domready',function(){
    $('.nav_main ul.level_2').masonry({ singleMode: true });
});
```

I'm not sure how I can select those lists, because what I'm doing is returning this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'masonry' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that your selector is returning null, so essentially you're trying to do this:

```
null.masonry();
```

which obviously wouldn't work.

In MooTools, the $ is used to select an element by its id. If you're going to select an array of elements, you need to use $$. See the [MooTools documentation on Elements](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element).

So, in your case, you should do this :

```
$$('.nav_main ul.level_2').masonry({ singleMode: true });
```

or perhaps, more simply:

```
$$('.level_2').masonry({ singleMode: true });
```